# Using MySQLdb --> conn.select_db() with Flask

Tags: python-2.7, flask, mysql-python

I've just figure it out that `MySQLdb` also has `conn.select_db()` fuction. Then I'd tried to combine it with `Flask` at the same time.
Here's my code:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
import MySQLdb

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/home")
def hello():
    return "Hello World"

# MySQL configurations
@app.route("/home/<string:db_name>/", methods=['GET'])
def db_show(db_name):
    conn = MySQLdb.connect("host","user","password")
    conn.select_db(db_name)
    cur = conn.cursor()
    sql = "SELECT user_id FROM activity_log"
    cur.execute(sql)
    data = cur.fetchone()
    return data


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

But I've got an error " `TypeError: 'long' object is not callable` ".
Questions : Can anyone please give me hints to fix this error? Or is that possible to use `conn.select_db()` the way I used it? Thanks

Errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1997, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1985, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1540, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1615, in full_dispatch_request
    return self.finalize_request(rv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1630, in finalize_request
    response = self.make_response(rv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1740, in make_response
    rv = self.response_class.force_type(rv, request.environ)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/wrappers.py", line 885, in force_type
    response = BaseResponse(*_run_wsgi_app(response, environ))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/test.py", line 884, in run_wsgi_app
    app_rv = app(environ, start_response)
TypeError: 'long' object is not callable
```

Comment: Which line cause that error?

Comment: @stamaimer just edit my question. You can see the errors there. Thanks

Comment: You should convert the data from long to str before return it.

Comment: Damn!!You are right. Thank you so much